# Wrtie a nested loop code segment that produces this output

Tags: loops, nested, output

Here is the output look like:

1

1 2

1 2 3

1 2 3 4

1 2 3

1 2

1

I can write it with two for loops but I don't know how to write it in just one nested loop. Is anyone can help me out? Appreciate.

Comment: Why does it have to be nested?

Comment: Also, if you show what you have tried we might want be able to help you figure out what you are doing wrong. I can post a solution if you like, but will you learn anything from it?

Comment: for (int line_1 = 1; line_1 <= 4; line_1++) {
                                                                                                                for (int number = 1; number <= line_1; number++){
    System.out.print(number + " ");   
   }
   System.out.println();
  }
  for (int line_2 = 4; line_2 >= 0; line_2--) {
    for(int count = 1; count <= line_2 - 1; count++){
     System.out.print(count + " ");
   }
   System.out.println();

Comment: omg. it messy. But that's what I did. I just dont know how to nested it in a loop. I have been working in this one for two hours. Can't find my own solution that's why I post up to here and ask for help

Comment: Can you please format it properly and edit you post?

Comment: Yeah if you can give me a solution that will be great. I can learn and mark it down to memorize it.

Comment: I dont know how to do it. I tried couple times to edit it but cannot work.

Comment: for (int line_1 = 1; line_1 <= 4; line_1++) { br/
                                                                                                                for (int number = 1; number <= line_1; number++){ br/
    System.out.print(number + " "); <br/>  
   }<br/>
   System.out.println();<br/>
  }<br/>
  for (int line_2 = 4; line_2 >= 0; line_2--) {<br/>
    for(int count = 1; count <= line_2 - 1; count++){<br/>
     System.out.print(count + " ");<br/>
   }<br/>
   System.out.println();<br/>

Comment: I dont know hot to break lines. T_T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't know it was Java, but this is one way of doing it:

```
boolean reverse = false;
int i = 1, max = 4;
do {
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) System.out.print(j+" ");
    System.out.println("");
    reverse = !reverse ? i == max : reverse;
    i = reverse ? i-1 : i+1;
}while(i > 0);
```

If you only want to use for-loops, you can switch the do-while with:

```
for(;i>0;) {
    /* same code */
}
```